# Python GUI, Tkinter vs Plotly Dash

Tags: user-interface, dashboard

Can somebody tell me the difference between Python Tkinter and Plotly Dash or streamlit?

I am trying to develop a dashboard for my machine learning model which I developed using python Jupiter notebook. But so far based on my searching, I can use Dash, or panel to build a dashboard and I can also use Tkinter to build a dashboard. So I am very confused when should I use what! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, do you want to create a dashboard app for Web GUI or Native GUI? If you prefer a native GUI, you can go with Tkinter. If you prefer Web, you can go with Dash or Streamlit.

Streamlit or Dash choice depends on your needs; if your project requires many customizations and interactivity, I would recommend Dash path.

Further, if you want to manage many pages and interactivity in that dashboard, I think the best choice is to go with the frontend stack. Last year I built a project which have many pages (pages have interactive maps, charts and diagrams), I tried to built with Streamlit or Dash, but these caused many problems. So I decided to use a JS library like Plotly.JS with a Bootstrap Dashboard Template.

Comment: Thanks. That's right helpful. I think I would like a web-based but multi-page dashboard with non-liner sequence. I wonder how easy it is using javascript to design the dashboard and link it with my NN model developed using tensflow. Any advice on that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Firstly, I don't know your case, so I'm just guessing now. If your web page for just prototype (without security concerns like authentication mechanisms or performance requirements like scalability, etc.), it will not be hard. If you havent expeirence with APIs, you can create an API using Flask or FastAPI for serving your model (for prediction) then test your API with suitable inputs. After that you can search "how works backend and frontend together" and "passing data from Backend to HTML with Flask." You will use that data (model prediction results for your example) to send JS vis. library.